# Identificar temas de conversación en ListView o Spinners

Tags: android

Tengo una base de datos [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) con Aulas y dentro de cada aula hay un tema de conversación. Desde mi aplicación Android me gustaría sacar un `ListView` o un `Spinner` sacando todas las aulas disponibles. Hasta aquí bien, se hacerlo, me conecto al servidor y con un adaptador meto los datos obtenidos de una tarea asíncrona a su `Layout` determinado.

De esta forma tengo en pantalla la posibilidad de elegir entre diferentes aulas, por ejemplo: Aula1, Aula2, Aula3, Aula4, etcétera. Pero sólo conozco el evento `setOnItemSelectedListener` que mediante el método `onItemSelected` y la sentencia `parent.getItemAtPosition(position)` me devuelve el número de la posición que ocupa en la lista o en el `Spinner`.

Pero ahora a continuación y en función del aula, los temas son distintos, con lo que me gustaría mostrar otro `Spinner` debajo o `ListView` en una nueva Activity o lo que sea, preguntando por otra lista (se obtendría de la base de datos remota) pero del aula en concreto, pero yo no dispongo de un evento que sea como los menús que permiten algo como:

```
switch (opcion_elegida) {
case 1:
// extraigo los temas de este aula y muestro un Spinner
break;

case 2:
// extraigo los temas de este aula y muestro un Spinner
break;

//etc
}
```

Puedo saber el número máximo de aulas pero como hago un case 0, case 1, case n... no sé si me explico.

El tema es peliagudo porque estoy intentando hacer como en jquery, si tal lista tiene un valor despliega esta otra lista en concreto obtenida de la BBDD.

¿Se os ocurre algo?

Gracias anticipadas.
Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

una opción puede ser por medio de un switch, donde llamarias un método que llene el spinner secundario, este método recibiria una lista de strings, dependiendonde tu aula elegida,  que seran los que llenen el spinner:

```
switch (opcion_elegida) {
case 1:
// extraigo los temas de este aula y muestro un Spinner
llenaSpinnerSecundario(obtieneDatosAula1());
break;

case 2:
// extraigo los temas de este aula y muestro un Spinner
llenaSpinnerSecundario(obtieneDatosAula2());
break;

//etc
}
```

para esto, crearías un método que llene el spinner secundario:

```
public void llenaSpinnerSecundario(List<String> spinnerArray){
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    Spinner sItems = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_secundario);
    sItems.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes declarar tus `Spinner` y hacer que respondan ambos al mismo `OnItemSelected` por medio de un `switch`, asi la carga seria de manera **Dinámica** cada que el usuario seleccione un elemento del primer `Spinner` seria algo como esto:

```
    private Spinner spinnerAuto, spinnerModelo;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.tu_layout);

            spinnerAuto = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerAuto);
            spinnerModelo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerModelo);

            // Aquí llenas el primer Spinner con tu metodo de servidor

            spinnerAuto.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            spinnerModelo.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

       }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        switch (parent.getId()) {
            case R.id.spinnerAuto:

                Log.d(TAG + " Auto seleccionado", String.valueOf(position));

                //Aqui llenas el segundo Spinner de manera dinámica dependiendo el seleccionado anteriormente igual desde tu servidor;

                break;

            case R.id.spinnerModelo:

                Log.d(TAG + " Modelo Seleccionado ", String.valueOf(position));

                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
```

Como puedes ver, el `Spinner` es ubicado por medio de su ID definido en el `layout`, el primero se carga con tu lista general de elementos a seleccionar y el segundo se carga de forma **Dinámica** dependiendo cual elemento se selecciono en el primero, puedes llenar varias listas de esta forma simplemente sentándolas al mismo `setOnItemSelectedListener`.